# photoswipe mixed paragraphs and images

Tags: html, css, image, photoswipe

Has anyone successfully implemented Photoswipe on a page where the images are spread throughout the page with paragraphs. I can combine the images into Photoswipe when the there is one paragraph or sentence between images, but not multiple paragraphs between images.

eg.

Image
Paragraph
Paragraph
Image
Paragraph
Paragraph
Paragraph
Image
Paragraph

```
<div class="imgDisplay monow" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">
  <figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
  <a href="assets/old/DSC02385.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="447x597">
  <img src="assets/old/DSC02385-m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" title="A Pole" alt="A Pole" />
  </a>
  <figcaption itemprop="caption description">A Pole</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
<a href="assets/old/DSC02403.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="600x450">
<img src="assets/old/DSC02403-m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" title="Much leaves." alt="Much leaves." />
</a>
<figcaption itemprop="caption description">Much leaves.</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
<a href="assets/old/DSC02409.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="600x450">
<img src="assets/old/DSC02409-m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" title="Yellow and Green" alt="Yellow and Green" />
</a>
<figcaption itemprop="caption description">Yellow and Green</figcaption>
<p>Paragraph of text</p>
<p>Paragraph of text</p>
</figure>

<p>Paragraph of text</p>
<p>Paragraph of text</p>

<figure itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
<a href="assets/old/DSC02411.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="600x450">
<img src="assets/old/DSC02411-m.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" title="Yellooooow and GREEEEEN" alt="Yellooooow and GREEEEEN" />
</a>
<figcaption itemprop="caption description">Yellooooow and GREEEEEN</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to post your code and a link. Typing the words Image and Paragraph is providing no information on your issue.

Comment: I have added the code. I have tried adding paragraphs inside the figure and outside the figure as shown.